# Polymer check if element is opened & assign css class to parent

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a Polymer element called `<collapse-item>`, which, when it is opened, gets an attribute `opened`. (`collapse-item` is based on `iron-collapse`) But how can I check with JS if this element is opened and then assign another css class to it's parent?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{booksList}}">
  <div class="parent">
    <h1>Some header</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <collapse-item input-text={{item.blurb}}></collapse-item>
  </div>
</template>
```

I only want to assign a new css class to this one instance of the `<div class="parent">` and not to all the others on the page.

**EDIT option 1**

I have changed the above to add a check for the opened item and added some js:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{booksList}}">
  <div class="parent" id="[[_toggleId]]">
    <h1>Some header</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <collapse-item input-text={{item.blurb}} opened="{{opened}}"></collapse-item>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
  properties: {

  _toggleId: {
      type: String,
      computed: '_computeToggleId(opened)'
    }

  },
  _computeToggleId: function(opened) {
      return opened ? 'expandeditem' : '';
  }
```

This creates the id not just for this once instance of the parent class, but all of them in the `dom-repeat`.

**EDIT option 2**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{booksList}}">
  <div class="parent" id="parentElem">
    <h1>Some header</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <collapse-item input-text={{item.blurb}} opened="{{opened}}" on-tap="_computeToggleId(opened)"></collapse-item>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
  _computeToggleId: function(opened) {
    if (opened) {
      this.$.parentElem.classList.add('expandeditem');
    }
```

Which cannot read the `classList` of `undefined`.

Thanks for helping me to learn. I'm new to Polymer.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind a property to opened attribute. here is the example for iron-collapse

```
<iron-collapse opened={{isOpen}}>
  <div class="parent" id="parentElem">
   <div>Content goes here...</div>
  </div>
</iron-collapse>
```

then you can check condition if(isOpen) is true or false, based on that change CSS class of parent element.
Assign  id to parent element and add or remove class name with id

```
      this.$.parentElem.classList.remove('YOUR_CSS_CLASS_NAME');
      this.$.parentElem.classList.add('YOUR_CSS_CLASS_NAME');
```

Comment: Problem is that if I do this, because it is in a `dom-repeat`, all the `<div class="parent">` will change and not just the one because the parent is outside the `iron-collapse`. I will edit the question to make it clearer what I have now.

Comment: I have edited the above question to give two options that both do not work. I have not much experience with Polymer yet so thanks for your help.

Comment: you can generate a dynamic id...then you can change css class of that perticular parent element with the help of dynamic id...like id="parent1", for first list and id="parent2" for second soo on...that can be done by adding index attribute of dom-repeat to id..like                                       <dom-repeat>                                                                                                   <div class="parent" id="parentElem[[index]]">